# Python - Regex to exclude some lines out of file

Tags: python, regex

Heres what the file of IPs looks like  :

```
# 111.111.111.111     <= exclude starting with # 
112.112.112.112 1     <= exclude one which has 1 next to it after space(s)
113.113.113.113 2     <= exclude one which has 2 next to it after space(s)
114.114.114.114 3     <= print this 
115.115.115.115 4     <= print this and so on
```

My take on this:

```py
ip = re.findall(r".*\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}[\s](?!1|2)", x)
```

This is not showing me the right IPs, I am a JS developer, would appreciate the help.

Comment: Do all lines have this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a charcter class to match either 0, or a digit 3-9.

```
^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+[03-9]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WrANdi/1)

If there can be more digits than 0 and 3-9, you could use an alternation also matching 2 or more digits.

```
^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+(?:[03-9]|\d{2,})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3qiXCV/1)

Comment: This works, but it only checks for single space, in my file, the ending numbers have single or more spaces before them. 
Can you help me with that too?

Comment: @KaranKumar You can use `\s+` to match 1 or more whitspace characters. Or use `[^\S\r\n]+` to match 1 or more whitspace characters without matching a newline. I have updated the answer.

Comment: By the looks of it you could just skip any lines which match `r'#|[12]$'`

Comment: @tripleee It would only not match the ip like format, but it will be ok if the format of all the lines are the same.

Answer (score 1):

What about returning the lines that do not start with `#` and do not have a `1` or `2` at the end:

```
import re

with open("ip.txt") as infile:  # change it to your real file name
    for line in infile:
        ip = line.strip()
        match = re.match(r"#(.+)|(.+?)\s+[12]$", ip)
        if not match:
            print(ip)
```

**Output**

```
114.114.114.114 3
115.115.115.115 4
```

Comment: The "anything" parts of the regex are completely redundant.

Comment: With this approach, you can even discard the regex altogether.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree

Answer (score 1):

This regex might help:

```
^(?:\d{3}\.){3}\d{3}\s+([^012]|\d{2,})\b
```

Note: re.MULTILINE is used since the flag '^' is used.

Comment: This option will also handle numbers larger than 9. A tricky number is for instance 22 in context '116.116.116.116 22' .

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
import re
data = '''# 111.111.111.111      
112.112.112.112 1
113.113.113.113 2
114.114.114.114 3 
115.115.115.115 4'''
ip = re.findall(r'^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b(?![\s]+[12])', data, re.MULTILINE)
print(ip)
```

Output:

```
['114.114.114.114', '115.115.115.115']
```

Explanation: `^` combined with `re.MULTILINE` - looks for substring spanning from start of line, `\b` make sure that whole adress is caught (prevent getting `112.112.112.11` for example), `(?![\s]+[12])` negative lookahead - one or more whitespaces followed by `1` or `2`. Note that python lookaheads might have variable length, whilst lookbehinds need to be fixed length.